# Relaying signals to contained widgets

Tags: python, pyside, signals-slots

I'm new to PySide, and trying to figure out how to elegantly create what is effectively a signal fanout; i.e. a doodad that looks like a Slot to container classes and can thus be connect()ed to, and simply forwards that signal on to contained classes, preferably without adding too much overhead in either syntax or performance.

Let's take an entirely contrived example:

```
class TripleCheckBox(QWidget):
    setCheckState = Signal(int)

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.checks = [QCheckBox(x, self) for x in ['One', 'Two', 'Three']]
        [self.setCheckState.connect(x) for x in self.checks]

class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        self.chk = QCheckBox('Alpha', self)
        self.btn = QPushButton('Push', self)
        self.tri = TripleCheckBox(self)
        self.chk.stateChanged.connect(self.tri.setCheckState)
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.clearChecks)

    def clearChecks(self):
        self.tri.setCheckState(0)
```

So, this does most of what I'm looking for. The stateChanged signal from the Alpha checkbox hits the signal port on the TripleCheckBox, which then rebroadcasts to One, Two, and Three, and (I believe) does so entirely inside the Qt library without having to bounce back and forth between library code and Python.

But `MainWindow.ClearChecks()` doesn't work. For a real QCheckBox, setCheckState is a Slot, and therefore a function, and can be called with conventional function syntax. But the setCheckState on the TripleCheckBox is a Signal, and so has to be "called" as `self.tri.setCheckState.emit(0)`

This is syntactically ugly, but also has some ugly mantainability implications. If I have a QCheckBox, I can treat setCheckState as a function. If I have a TripleCheckBox, I have to treat it as a signal instead, even though all it's doing is wrapping up 3 QCheckBoxes.

Ideally, TripleCheckBox.setCheckState would be a thing like a Signal that simply has a `__call__` method that calls/is `emit`. But you can't inherit from Signal.

I can think of several inelegant ways to do this, all of which involving lots of replication of code and adhocery. But this is some pretty basic level stuff, surely there's an elegant answer. Right?

Answer (score 1):

The use of a custom signal in your example is redundant, and makes the code unnecessarily complicated.

Given its name and intended usage, `TripleCheckBox.setCheckState`, should be a slot rather than a signal. A signal should not, in itself, *do* anything: it is simply a notification that some event has happened (or is about to happen). A signal should have no direct side-effects, and any object broadcasting it should not care about what consequences (if any) it may have once it's been emitted.

For this reason, the line `self.tri.setCheckState(0)`, makes no sense *as a signal* (although it does as a slot). On the other hand, something like `self.tri.stateChanged.emit(0)` *would* make sense (although not necessarily in that particular context).

Given the above points, here is one way to re-write your example:

```
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui

class CheckBoxSet(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, labels, parent=None):
        super(CheckBoxSet, self).__init__(parent)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.checkboxes = []
        for label in labels:
            checkbox = QtGui.QCheckBox(label, self)
            layout.addWidget(checkbox)
            self.checkboxes.append(checkbox)

    def setCheckState(self, state=0):
        state = QtCore.Qt.CheckState(state)
        for checkbox in self.checkboxes:
            checkbox.setCheckState(state)

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.chk = QtGui.QCheckBox('Alpha', self)
        self.btn = QtGui.QPushButton('Push', self)
        self.tri = CheckBoxSet('One Two Three'.split(), self)
        layout.addWidget(self.chk)
        layout.addWidget(self.btn)
        layout.addWidget(self.tri)
        self.chk.stateChanged.connect(self.tri.setCheckState)
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.clearChecks)

    def clearChecks(self):
        self.tri.setCheckState(0)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.setGeometry(500, 300, 300, 200)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```